# How do you create an array of a certain size using malloc() in C?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc

Part of the program I am writing requires an array to be created using malloc instead of the regular way of doing it. I have to have the user enter a number, assign that number the name MAX, and create an array using malloc() with numbers 2 through the number entered. How would I go about coding this?

Comment: Start with a nice book.

Comment: Kind of hard to do at a friends house at 1 in the morning....

Comment: That's why I lurves the Interweb.

Comment: Shouldn't your friend's instructor have covered how to do this sort of thing before assigning the homework?

Comment: if you type the word 'malloc' into any search engine there will be BILLIONS of hits!

Comment: Whys it always so complicated for people to just answer a question posted? I feel like its rocket science...

Comment: google "malloc array" - see first hit.  (-1 for research skills)

Comment: Fair enough, then: Shouldn't _your_ instructor have covered the technique before assigning homework?

Comment: This is not a chat board, it's an archival of questions and answers, and there are rules that help eliminate the chaff.

Comment: Should he have? Yes Did he, No. Just said look at the book, which I do not have with me.

Answer (score 2):

You create an "array" with [`malloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html) by specifying the size (in bytes) of the array and assigning the return value to a pointer of the appropriate type. If you're intending for this to be an array of objects that are larger than one byte, you can multiply the number of objects by the size of the object, which can be obtained with the `sizeof` operator.

For example, you can create an "array" of fifty `int` objects like so:

```
int *ar = malloc(50 * sizeof (int) );
```

Comment: Thank you! Thats all I needed to know.

Comment: When I do this I get an error saying: expected declaration or statement at end of input
int *ar = malloc(50 * sizeof (int) );

Comment: If you're using a sufficiently old C compiler, such as Microsoft Visual Studio, it won't support intermixed statements and declarations. Put `int *ar = NULL;` at the beginning of the function, and at the place where you need to allocate it, put `ar = malloc( whatever );`. Make sure to substitute the appropriate values for "whatever", of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by:

```
T *dynamic_memory;
.......  //Get the desired array size from user input and store in 'array_max_size'
dynamic_memory=malloc((sizeof(T) * array_max_size);
```

`T` : data type of array

You can then use `dynamic_memory` for your purpose.